# DataGridView DefaultCellStyle.BackColor not applying using my if statement

Tags: c#

I am aiming to apply style to a row where status equals to `Rejected`. Trouble is, my code is not applying the style.

**Code**

```
    public void RefreshGrid()
    {
        // MySQL connection string
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
        {
            using (var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select id, name, status from table", conn))
            {
                using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
                {
                    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
                    dataGrid.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
                    dataGrid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
                    dataGrid.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
                    dataGrid.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Status";

                    // Set visibility to none
                    dataGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Where status = Rejected format cell style to Red
        foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dataGrid.Rows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Myrow.Cells[2].Value.ToString()); // This shows me `Rejected` and some `Verified`
            if (Myrow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Rejected")
            {
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Summary**

I am confused to why it is not applying the red? I have used this code before and worked fine.

Have even used `MessageBox.Show()` to confirm some rows contain value of `Rejected`.

Where am I going wrong?

**Edit 1**

Setting else statement to red like so

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in documentRequestsHistory.Rows)
{
    if (Myrow.Cells[12].Value.ToString() == "Rejected")
    {
        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Does not apply any styles.

Comment: Do your If statement evaluate as true? You can try with the string Equals function.

Comment: @ClovisIgnacioFerreira setting the `BackColor` to `Red` in `else` statement - does not apply too.

Comment: Did the answer provided by @Shayama solve the problem?

Comment: @ClovisIgnacioFerreira I don't think `UseBackColor` is a code in C# winforms?

Comment: Did you try to create a DataGridViewCellStyle object, set the BackColor property of this new object to Color.Red, and assign the Myrow.DefaultCellStyle of your row to this new object?

Comment: @ClovisIgnacioFerreira you mean `CellFormatting`? not `CellStyle`.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-default-cell-styles-for-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) my help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red color doesn't apply in your code because the DataGridView has no way yet to check the values of the column in question and set the desired cell-style accordingly. Actually, the `foreach` block is just switching the `BackColor` property of the entire column.

To make it work, handle the `CellFormatting` event to check the values of the target column then set the desired style:

```cs
private void dataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = e.Value?.ToString().ToLower() == "rejected" 
            ? Color.Red 
            : Color.White;
}
```

To switch the `BackColor` of the row:

```cs
private void dataGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        ((DataGridView)sender)
            .Rows[e.RowIndex]
            .DefaultCellStyle
            .BackColor = e.Value?.ToString().ToLower() == "rejected" 
            ? Color.Red 
            : Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Instead of cell - how would you do full row being red?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try apply UseBackColor = true before or after set red?